Breaker trips with daisy chained gfci’s
Let me preface this with I didn’t install this system so I’m having to figure it out as I go. I have an outdoor camera setup with direct burial wire. I have one circuit that keeps tripping at the breaker. They daisy chained 4 gfci together. I have isolated the issue a bit.

I changed gfci 1 to start- breaker pop
Removed the daisy chain wire and all is good, gfci works and reads 120
Added the daisy chain back
Unhooked gfci 3 to isolate- breaker pop
Unhooked gfci 2 to isolate- breaker pop
Remove gfci 1 and test with regular outlet- still pops breaker

I also changed the breaker, tested sub panel and main panel and everything reads correctly. Does that mean the wire between gfci 1 and 2 is shot? It is direct burial 2.5 ft down across like 200 ft- hoping I am missing something so I don’t have to trench this whole thing.

Daisy-chaining GFCIs does not cause false trips (although it adds nothing and makes resets difficult, so there is no reason to do it). You probably do have damaged wiring.

Is the breaker a plain breaker or AFCI or GFCI?

Just a plain breaker. Thanks nobody, cant believe I’m just thinking I could have tested a new small run of wire while I was out there- oops will do that next

@Kevin, to test the wire between GFCI 1 & 2, diconnect it at both ends and then measure the resistance between black and white wires. A good cable reads infinity and a shorted cable reads a very low value (probably single-digit Ohm).

When you say daisy chained, is that coming off of GFCI 1's LOAD connectors or pigtailed with the incoming hot (LINE)? In the first case, you can replace the other three outlets with regular non-GFCI type - the first will provide protection to the rest of the outlets and all the cables between (also makes troubleshooting a bit easier). In the latter scenario, each GFCI works independently, though there is no protection on the cabling between them. You likely have a (very bad) fault between GFCI 1 & 2 somewhere - bad because the breaker is popping, not just the GFCI, so 10's of amps are shorting
